# how to know most derived implementation in virtual\override

Tags: c#

### I can't figure out the exact reason for the method call, how to know which method will be called when there are multiple virtual and override in case of multilevel inheritance ?

```
 public class A
    {
        public virtual void f1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public override void f1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }

    public class C:B
    {
        public override void f1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }

    public class D:C
    {
        public virtual void f1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D");
        }
    }

    public class E : D
    {
        public override void f1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("E");
        }
    }


A aobj = new D(); 
aobj.f1();
//why output is "C" here

A aobj = new E();
aobj.f1();
//why output is again "C" and not "E"
```

I am confused and need the help of others to understand, how the compiler decides which function to call ?

Comment: The method in class D is implicitly marked as virtual since one of the super classes marks it as virtual, and since the method in D is not marked as override then it will hide the ones defined in it's super classes.

Comment: And since aobj is of type A, the object will only call the last overriden method for f1 that defined in A. I recommend you to read more about polymorphism

Comment: This scenario is just for demo purpose and not actual real world. I was asked this in an interview and I could not answer. I just want to understand the reason, what is making the compiler call "C", so that instead of just learning it by heart I understand the actual reason.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the `virtual` keyword is used for `D.f1()`, instead of `override`. There is no need to mark `D.f1()` as `virtual` since the base method `A.f1()` is already virtual.

I'm not sure if you've noticed that your current code throws a `CS0114` warning:

```
CS0114: 'D.f1()' hides inherited member 'C.f1()'. 
To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. 
Otherwise add the new keyword.
```

Changing `class D` to the following will correct the issue:

```
public class D:C
{
    public override void f1()    // Notice use of 'override' instead of 'virtual' 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D");
    }
}
```

With the above change, the expected output is returned:

```
D
E
```

Take a look at these 2 questions which discuss a very similar issue:

- [Resolving the "most derived" method in a virtual override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679293/resolving-the-most-derived-method-in-a-virtual-override)
- [What if I don't heed the warning "hides inherited member. To make the current member override that implementation...."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933045/what-if-i-dont-heed-the-warning-hides-inherited-member-to-make-the-current-me)

---

**EDIT: Rationale Behind the Behaviour**

`aobj` is an instance of `class A`. Therefore, work from the base class A upwards to identify which version of `f1()` is called. The **highest overridden method** is `C.f1()` hence that will be called. The hierarchy of overrides has been broken in class D by using `virtual`, hence `D.f1()` and `E.f1()` aren't called when using an instance of `class A`.

Comment: This scenario is just for demo purpose and not actual real world. I was asked this in an interview and I could not answer. I just want to understand the reason, what is making the compiler call "C", so that instead of just learning it by heart I understand the actual reason.

Comment: To rephrase, I want to understand how compiler is resolving it and if its going by "most derived" thing, how does it determine which is the most derived thing.

Comment: @RaviKumar - I've edited my answer to add a _Rationale_ section at the end that provides a brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

in your class D you are again using virtual you need to use the override, which hides the inheritance for c.F1()

```
public class D:C
{
    public virtual void f1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D");
    }
}
```

Comment: This scenario is just for demo purpose and not actual real world. I was asked this in an interview and I could not answer. I just want to understand the reason, what is making the compiler call "C", so that instead of just learning it by heart I understand the actual reason.

Comment: The way it works, as you are creating object of class A but initializing it with Class D, and trying to call method f1(), this type of call will try to go to last override method which is C.f1() as this chain is broken in Class D(), that's why C.f1() is called. sorry for late reply was busy ..